# Daily unique visitors reporting in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Does anybody know if there is any way to get the total number of daily unique visitors on a given period of time (e.g. a month) in Google Analytics?

(normally Analytics would just show the number of unique visitors for the month and not the sum of unique daily visitors in that amount of time).

Comment: hmm maybe I'm missing something or not understanding the question, so maybe you can clarify...but when you go to the unique visitors report (or any report for that matter) you can specify the date range and it will show you totals for the time period you select.

Comment: Exactly, but this still doesn't answer my question.

Let's consider a simple example. On the 1st of January your website is visited by the users "A, B and C". On the 2nd of January is visited by the users "B, C and D".

Now, if you look at the total "unique visitors" in Google Analytics for the period 1st-2nd of January it will say "4" (because it sums A, B, C and D). 

What I want to know though is if it's possible to see the "daily unique visitors" for the same period, which would  be "6" ("A, B, C" for the first day, and "B, C, D" for the second day).

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics has not such metrics as daily, weekly, monthly etc. unique visitors, it only has "unique visitors over selected time period". And you can't use it anywhere, since GA is visit based and not visitor. If you really want to measure unique visitors over a time period, use custom variables.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, could you please also tell me how should I set custom variables (step by step) to obtain the data I need?

Comment: You can find more about the custom variables from Google's Help section. Has a comprehensive guide of the variables, their settings and basic ways to set them (the default sample is for the new asynchronous format, which is recommended): [GA Tracking API](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html)

Answer (score 3):

Make a custom report and under the filters tab select "Visitor-"Visitor Type" to get new and returning customers.  A "new" customer is someone who accesses the website for the first time during your selected data range, and not the first time someone views your website (unique).  You can read more about [New/Returning vs. Unique Visitors here.](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/07/30/absolute-unique-unique-visitors-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1382638957)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting up a custom dimension and send a unique id for every user in this dimension. Ensure not to send email/twitter handle etc as this ID, since they violate the privacy terms of Google Analytics. Ideally this ID is a unique internal userID from your server.

Once you do this, you can query the report using this dimension and date. This will give one row for each user's daily visit. Count of these rows compared to the time period, say 6 months will give you the DAU/MAU etc.

There is a setup require in Analytics Site, change in tracking code and preferably use the API or Query explorer tool to fetch the data and compute what you need.

I have made a detailed write up after finding no complete article on it: [DAU/MAU Sticky users Measurements in Google Analytics](http://www.notingon.com/dau-mau-measurements-in-google-analytics/)

See if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Audience >> Overview, choose Users metric over a period (i.e. month) and extract to excel file (XLSX). 
Under DataSet1 label you'll find all data on a daily resolution. from there you can calculate the average easily.
Perhaps not the most elegant way but still an easy one :-)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this.  In GA, just go to Audience >> Overview.  Select the date range that you want.  The unique visitors during this date range is listed below the chart in the box labeled "Unique Visitors".

In the Overview chart, you also select to see your data graphed hourly, daily, weekly, or monthly.  On the left hand side, select "Unique Visitors" from the metric drop-down picker.  That will give you your daily/weekly/monthly data.

Note that the daily unique visitors will not add up to the weekly or monthly unique visitors.  If Joe visited on Tuesday and Wednesday, he will count as a unique visitor on each of those days.  But he will only count once as a unique visitor for the weekly number.

My company's tool - [Megalytic](http://megalytic.com) - lets you easily generate custom reports that can give you a lot of information about unique visitors - by country, landing page, referral source, social network, etc.  You can get all this information by building custom reports in Google Analytics also, but we make it pretty and easy to share or print out as a PDF, and you can put as many custom reports on a single page as you want.